# JavaScript test case for isElementInViewport

Tags: javascript, jestjs, testcase

I am new to the test case, can anyone help me for writing test case for `isElementInViewport` JavaScript function

```
function isElementInViewport(ele) {
  const rect = ele.getBoundingClientRect()
  const InViewPort = (
    rect.top >= 0 &&
    rect.left >= 0 &&
    rect.bottom <= 0 &&
    rect.right <= 0
  )
  return InViewPort
}
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. Even just getting the test running environment setup would tell us how new you are. You might want to take a tutorial or two on jest (like their [Getting Started](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started.html) page, and the rest of the documentation there).

Comment: You might be interested in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
export function isElementInViewport(ele) {
  const rect = ele.getBoundingClientRect();
  const InViewPort =
    rect.top >= 0 && rect.left >= 0 && rect.bottom <= 0 && rect.right <= 0;
  return InViewPort;
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { isElementInViewport } from "./";

describe("isElementInViewport", () => {
  it("t-1", () => {
    const mEl = {
      getBoundingClientRect: jest
        .fn()
        .mockReturnValueOnce({ top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0 })
    };
    const actual = isElementInViewport(mEl);
    expect(actual).toBeTruthy();
    expect(mEl.getBoundingClientRect).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59057693/index.spec.ts
  isElementInViewport
    ✓ t-1 (5ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.018s, estimated 12s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59057693